# Notepad++ Delete 9 characters after a string

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

I am looking for a way to delete 9 characters after a string :

vimeo.com/600984066

I want to only have vimeo.com/ is there a way to do it with maybe regex ?

Important : I have some content after so i can't delete the 9 last characters of a line.

Comment: I found a solution using (?=vimeo\.com).{18}, hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using (?=vimeo\.com).{18}, hope that will help someone.

Comment: why selecting 18 characters where as you initialy asked for 9...?